# directory / file is exist or not using Typescript

Tags: typescript, input, output

**There is any way to check if there is any directory/file is exist in location and create using typescript ?**

I tried to google but all are in js example I need to know how to do in typescript to that operation

Comment: Browser? NodeJS?

Comment: google chrome, yes NodeJs project with angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the following function, it attempts to create a folder (which errors if it does not exist) and then calls you back.

Functions for folders and files shown:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';

export function createDirectory(path: string, mask: number | null, cb: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException | null) => void) {
    if (!mask) {
        mask = 484; //0744
    }

    fs.mkdir(path, mask, (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException) => {
        if (err && err.code !== 'EEXIST') {
            // Error (not folder already exists)
            cb(err);
            return;
        }

        // Folder created, or already exists
        cb(null);
    });
}

export function createFile(path: string, cb: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException | null) => void) {
    fs.stat(path, (err, stat) => {
        if (err) {
            if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                // Create the File
                fs.writeFile(path, '', (err) => {
                    cb(err);
                });
            } else {
                // Error
                cb(err);
            }
        } else {
            // File already exists
            cb(null);
        }
    });
}
```

It has all the appropriate type annotations that you need to guide you.

Comment: File version added.

Comment: hello @Fenton there is [mask: number] what is this mask for ?

Comment: That's for the directory permissions: http://www.filepermissions.com/directory-permission/0744